# Android Constraint Layout position view below parent

Tags: android, animation, android-constraintlayout

I want to make "slide in" animation to my view in Constraint Layout with Constraint Set and Transition Manager. For this I need to position my view below the parent view. So it will slide out from screen and slide back ti the screen. Is it possible in Constraint Layout?

In code I need my `index_navigation` position below the parent view.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/page_number"
    style="@style/RoundBackgroundStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/page_number_round_bg"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

<me.example.ui.extensions.PageNavigator
    android:id="@+id/index_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/index_scroll_background"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/index_navigation_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        />
</me.example.ui.extensions.PageNavigator>
```

Animation code

```
val constraintSet1 = ConstraintSet()
        constraintSet1.clone(rootView)
        val constraintSet2 = ConstraintSet()
        constraintSet2.clone(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        constraintSet2.setTranslationY(R.id.index_navigation, 150f)

        viewModel.shouldShowIndexPagerLiveEvent.observe(this, Observer { shouldShow ->
            shouldShow?.let {
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootView)
                val constraint = if (it) constraintSet1 else constraintSet2
                constraint.applyTo(rootView)
            }
        })
```

Comment: cannot you use `ViewPropertyAnimator#translationYBy` ?

Comment: Is it possible with ConstraintLayout?

Comment: it is possible with any layout imho

Comment: btw you want to create something like [Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/training/snackbar/showing.html)? *You can use a Snackbar to display a brief message to the user. The message automatically goes away after a short period. A Snackbar is ideal for brief messages that the user doesn't necessarily need to act on. For example, an email app could use a Snackbar to tell the user that the app successfully sent an email.*

Comment: No, I want to add page navigation for horizontal recyclerview, I wan to hide it if user scrolls content up, and show it back when user scroll down

Comment: Indeed `indexNavigation.animate().translationY(if (show) indexNavigation.height.toFloat() else 0f)` did the trick. Thank you @pskink

Comment: your welcome, btw cannot you extend [BaseTransientBottomBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BaseTransientBottomBar.html) which in 99% already implements the grunt / dirty work?

Comment: I will give it a try

Comment: @pskink I decided to go with extended FrameLayout, since its already working and I also process onTouch event from that view.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the position of index_navigation? Something like this.

```
index_navigation_view.setY(parent_view_height)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have found an answer, but figured I would bring up another possibility that exists, which is to use MotionLayout (which is an extension of ConstraintLayout), available for API 18 and up.

Here is a [link](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motion-layout) to the developer tutorial.